# How to bind a label in gridview with zero to a null value from sql server

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi all I am having an integer value `null` in my table, I would like to bind it to gridview label with `0` when the value is `null`, for a `nullable` string I write this which works fine but the same with changes didn't work can some one help

`<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("call").ToString()) ? "NULL" : Eval("call"))%>'></asp:Label>`

The same for Integer I write as follows

`<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("send2").ToString()) ? "0" : Convert.ToInt16(Eval("send2")).ToString() %>`

This didn't worked, any help appreciated

Comment: try this `Eval("send2") == null ? "0" : (Int16)Eval("send2");`

Comment: no luck DON, `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'short'`

Comment: Probably that is a conversion problem, try this `Eval("send2") == null ? "0" : Convert.ToInt16(Eval("send2"));`

Comment: @Dotnet Try `Eval("send2")==System.DBNull` or even `Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("send2")) ? "0" : Convert.ToInt16(Eval("send2")).ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the null variables you usually use the `System.DBNull` , so you code can be:

```
Eval("send2")==System.DBNull ?  "0" : Convert.ToInt16(Eval("send2")).ToString()
```

or aleternative:

```
Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("send2")) ? "0" : Convert.ToInt16(Eval("send2")).ToString()
```